# Rename values in column

Tags: dataframe, rename, julia

How to rename all values in specific column in dataframe?
I was thinking that something like this should work:

```
dfProducts[:StandardCost] = replace(dfProducts[:StandardCost], "£", convert(UTF8String,""))
```

But it didnt.

> `replace` has no method matching replace(::DataArray{UTF8String,1},
>   ::UTF8String, ::UTF8String)

In general the values in this column are in format "£0,000.00" and I was thinking to replace the "£" and "," and convert them to Float type because I need to multiply them with another column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
dfProducts[:StandardCost] = map(x->replace(x, "£", convert(UTF8String,"")), dfProducts[:StandardCost])
```

EDIT: You can extend the method if you want to keep this workaround somewhere else (ie "maybe improve readability")

```
Base.replace(a::DataArray{UTF8String,1}, s::UTF8String, r::UTF8String) = map(x->replace(x, s, r),a)
#...
dfProducts[:StandardCost] = replace(dfProducts[:StandardCost], "£", convert(UTF8String,""))
```

Do mind that neither method is optimal compute-wise or continuous-memory-alloc'd-wise, but I guess that's out of the scope of the question